# Hi, I am a newbie in this Javascript. I just wanna ask on how to validate input from a form. Can you check up on my code?

Tags: javascript, input

Sorry Just a newbie here in javascript. I just want to know what is the problem with my code. I have searched and searched doesn't seem to find the answer. Any answer is very much appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h2>Credit Card Validation</h2>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["Num"].value;
    var z = document.forms["myForm"]["Date"].value;
    var ver_num = /^ \d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/;
    var ver_date =  /^([0-9]){2}(\/)([0-9]){4}$/;  

    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
}

    if ( y.match(ver_num) ){
    alert("Input the right credit card no. format");
    return false;   
}    

    if ( ver_date.test(z) ){
    alert ("Input the right date format");
    return false;
}



}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()"     method="post"><pre>
Name:           <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Leonardo De Caprio" >
Card type & number: <select name="days"><option value='1'>VISA</option>
<option value='2'>Master</option><option value='3'>JCB</option>
<input type="text" name="Num" placeholder = "0000-0000-0000-0000" size = "22" >
Date of Expiration: <input type="text" name="Date" size = "34" placeholder = "MM/YYYY">
</pre>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't like guessing games. Why don't you tell us what the problem is, and we'll try to fix it.

Comment: The first condition is alright. It is functioning. But the next two aren't. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

```
if ( ver_date.test(z) ){
    alert ("Input the right date format"); //you have used  alert ("Input the right date format") add the semicolem
    return false;
```

also change `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to `onsubmit="return validateForm();"`

Updated add

```
var ver_num = '/^ \d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}$/';
var ver_date =  '/^([0-9]){2}(\/)([0-9]){4}$/';
```

Comment: placed the right semicolons and added the quotations. but nothing changed.

Comment: you need to change this match() method for validation, try regex or something else

Comment: what will I replace it with? (Sorry for the noob question.)